# Error with fgets usage in c

Tags: c, stack, fgets

I have written a balanced symbol checker with stacks. Everything else works and I have fully tested all functions like pop push destroy isempty. The problem is my fgets usage.

```
//fgets
char input[10];
printf("Enter a 10 character input for balance: ");
fgets(input, 10, stdin);
```

the part that is "not working" is the following code

```
int i = 0;
for (i < 10; i++;){
    if (input[i] == '{' || input[i] == '[' || input[i] == '(' || input[i] == '<'){
        push(&st2, input[i]);

    }
}
```

I know my push function is working, because i have tested it as a standalone. something like:

```
push(&st2, '{');
```

works perfectly fine when i try to display my stack and correctly pushes the value. 
At this point I am thinking that either the initial char array with fgets is just not initializing correctly, or I have somehow managed to screw up the if/for loop.

When I run the program the if statement conditional is never met even if i type a { [ ( or < into stdin. When I try to print our the input[10] char array my program just crashes aswell.

Comment: did you check fgets(input, 10, stdin) != NULL?

Comment: `input` can only store 9 characters of input (followed by the `'\0'` terminator).

Answer (score 4):

The for loop is wrong.

Try

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ...
}
```

instead.

The correct syntax is

```
for (initialisation; condition; increment) {
    body
}
```

So if you write this:

```
int i = 0;
for (i < 10; i++; ) {
    ...
}
```

the following happens:

First the initialisation occurs. `i < 10` is executed, but it is a simple logical expression which evaluates to `true` and is ignored. Then the condition is checked. `i++` evaluates to 0 (not to 1, because of the *post*-increment), which is interpreted as `false` and the loop terminates.

Comment: I don't see how this changes anything. I was taught that you can initialize i outside of a for loop.

Comment: @user3457828 Yes, but you need at least one **;** more which will be **for(;i<10;i++)** do you see the difference ? In your code the ; is used at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems in your code.

1)

```
char input[10];
printf("Enter a 10 character input for balance: ");
```

Should be:

```
    char input[11];
```

You need the '\0' too.

2)

```
    fgets(input, 10, stdin);
```

Always check return:

```
    if (fgets(input, 10, stdin) != NULL){}
```

3)

```
    for (i < 10; i++;){}
```

Is wrong, it should be:

```
    for (;i < 10; i++){}
```

Do you see the difference ?

Now we can put them all together:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char input[11];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter a 10 character input for balance: ");
    if (fgets(input, 10, stdin) != NULL){
        for (;i < 10; i++){
            /* do what you need here */
        }
    }
        printf("Goodbye\n");
    return 0;
}
```